# New filter operation implementation by a different field of id field in JHipster

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I have the next list operations in the API with JHipster:
[attached file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A3p0.jpg)
However, I need to filter by another field different to the id field (GET / api/ reservas/ {id}). What should I do to create a new operation GET request for this field?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an optional request parameter.

For instance, if you want to filter `reservas` with `capacidad` equal to 1:

```
GET /api/reservas?capacidad=1
```

```
@GetMapping
public List<Reservas> findAll(@RequestParam(value = "capacidad", required = false) int capacidad) {
```

Comment: Could I also filter by a field of the next way? if there is a ReservasCriteria.java implementation.

  this.reservasService.query({
        'capacidad.equals' : 1
      }).pipe(
          filter((res: HttpResponse<Reservas[]>) => res.ok),
          map((res: HttpResponse<Reservas[]>) => res.body)
      )....

Comment: I don't understand your point, are you refering to JHipster entity filtering? https://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/#-filtering-your-entities

Comment: Yeah, could I use the JHipster entity filtering to filter with an optional request parameter like the previous sample?.

Comment: If you use entity filtering, you would not need to make it optional, it's already covered.